# Angular2 FormBuilder: Using 'this' in a custom validator

Tags: angularjs, angular, formbuilder

I'm developing a form using Angular2's FormBuilder with custom validation. 
Problem: In customValidator I'm using `this` to access the local object `data`. I'm getting a `undefined` error when the validation is executed.

It looks like the customValidator is executed in a different object and therefore changing the `this` reference

**Question:** How can I pass a reference of `this` to the customValidator?

```
export class Ast {
    public data:any;
    public myForm:FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.data = {foo: "bar"};
    }

    customValidator(c: FormControl) {
        if (this.data.foo == "bar") { // This line crashes
            // DO something
        }
    }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.myForm = this._fb.group({
           some_field: ['', [<any>Validators.required], this.customValidator]
       })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an arrow function, to make sure the function is bound to this:

```
some_field: ['', [<any>Validators.required], c => this.customValidator(c)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to send "this.data.foo" as a parameter to the function "customValidator"? If so, how?

Comment: No: Angular will call the validator function, and will only pass one argument. But you're kind of doing that by binding the function to `this`, and accessing `this` from inside the function. You could also pass the data to a function that would create and return the validator function, using the closure mechanism. But an arrow function is simpler.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me in Angular 2.0 due to typing issues (casting an `AbstractControl` to a `FormControl`, I believe).  The following, however, solved the problem quite nicely:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        some_field: ['', [<any>Validators.required], this.customValidator.bind(this)]
    });
}
```

Using the `.bind(this)` on the reference to the validator did the trick for me.