# Angular2 Custom Form Validators losing access to `this` in class

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, this

I'm building an Angular 2 application (2.0) and I've got a form that makes use of the `ReactiveForms` module.  As such, I'm using validator functions on the input fields, including custom validators.  This works fine.

My issue is that I am also trying to use a custom AsyncValidator on a form field.  It seems straight forward enough, but I can never reference properties inside the class from within the AsyncValidator method.

The `FormGroup` and the `FormControl` properties for the form itself and the input field look like this in the component's class:

```
form: FormGroup;
userName = new FormControl("", [Validators.required], [this.userNameAsyncValidator]);
```

There's also a `FormBuilder` in the `ngOnInit()` function that attaches the form to the `form` property.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, // this.fb comes from here
          private css: ClientSecurityService) { // this.css comes from here
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      "userName": this.userName
    }
  );
}
```

My issue is that in the AsyncValidator, I am unable to reference any of the services I've defined in the component's class - including `this.css`.  Here's the validator:

```
userNameAsyncValidator(control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.css.getUrl()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('Returned http data:', data);
          resolve(null);
        },
        err => {
          // Log errors if any
          console.log(err);
        });
  });
}
```

No matter what I do, `this.css` in the `userNameAsyncValidator()` call is undefined.

(I realize that my validator doesn't actually do anything - I just want to be able to call my ClientSecurity service so that I can, eventually, call a remote HTTP webservice to get a response as to whether the userName being entered is valid and not already in use.)

Comment: As you are using an arrow function, the problem is probably that the `userNameAsyncValidator` function isn't bound to the right `this`. Who invokes this function? How is this function passed? If you pass it then pass it like so: `this.userNameAsyncValidator.bind(this)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 FormBuilder: Using 'this' in a custom validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329920/angular2-formbuilder-using-this-in-a-custom-validator)

Comment: @NitzanTomer It's a likely a class (prototype) method, which cannot be defined with an arrow function

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your validator is not being called with your component as `this`. Notice that you are passing a loose reference to `this.userNameAsyncValidator` You can bind your validator without worrying about `this` conflicts because  angular validation doesn't rely on `this`

```
userName = new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required
], [
    this.userNameAsyncValidator.bind(this)
]);
```